# An object or column name is missing or empty. But its not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am on the 7th set of queries I have been working on and all of them have used `SELECT * INTO some_table` without an issue. For some reason tho the below query in SQL Server is throwing the error

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO
>   statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look
>   for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed.
>   Change the alias to a valid name.

Any Idea on what it could be?
Note that running the query without the `select into` will result in data being returned and displayed as expected.

```
Select * into MYDB.MY_TBL
SELECT OT.U_ID AS "U_ID"
    ,R.E AS "E"
    ,R.IR AS "CKT"
    ,A.RI AS "OC"
    ,A.EQ AS "SEQ"
    ,A.HA AS "CHA"
    ,A.A_HA AS "ATE"
    ,A.BIL AS "BIL"
    ,A.CHA AS "CHAA"
    ,A.RAT AS "AMT"
    ,A.PRM AS "PREM"
    ,A.T_CHG AS "RAT"
    ,A.PER AS "LAS"
    ,A.S_BIL AS "BIL_A"
    ,A.CD AS "CDE"
    ,A.CBIL_J AS "BIL_J"
    ,A.AMT_D AS "TB"
    ,A.CRY AS "CTRY"
    ,A.RVW AS "RVW"

FROM MYDB.OTHER_TBL OT
JOIN [LINKEDSERVER\INST,0000].FE.dbo.tblR R
    ON OT.E = R.E
JOIN [LINKEDSERVER\INST,0000].FE.dbo.tblA A
    ON R.IR = A.IR

WHERE OT.U_ID = 'TEST'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `select`s.  I think you just want:

```
SELECT OT.U_ID AS "U_ID",
       . . .
INTO MYDB.MY_TBL
FROM . . .
```

The `INTO` should follow the `SELECT` column list.

Or alternatively, you could use a subquery, but that does not seem necessary.

Comment: You know what I was totally missing my `from () ` sub query setup... I got it now. Just fighting with it for an hour now and just needed to go away and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Where @GordonLinoff example works I realized what I forgot and it was my `FROM ()` sub-query setup I normally use.

I will provide an example in contrast to Gordon's method.

IE:

```
Select * into MYDB.MY_TBL
FROM(
SELECT OT.U_ID AS "U_ID"
    ...
FROM MYDB.OTHER_TBL OT
WHERE OT.U_ID = 'TEST'
) SUB
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note these two points:

1.You have two columns with given "CHA" alias

2.It Seems you need to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT OT.U_ID AS "U_ID"
    ,R.E AS "E"
    ,R.IR AS "CKT"
    ,A.RI AS "OC"
    ,A.EQ AS "SEQ"
    ,A.HA AS "CHA_DUPLICATE"
    ,A.A_HA AS "ATE"
    ,A.BIL AS "BIL"
    ,A.CHA AS "CHA_DUPLICATE2"
    ,A.RAT AS "AMT"
    ,A.PRM AS "PREM"
    ,A.T_CHG AS "RAT"
    ,A.PER AS "LAS"
    ,A.S_BIL AS "BIL_A"
    ,A.CD AS "CDE"
    ,A.CBIL_J AS "BIL_J"
    ,A.AMT_D AS "TB"
    ,A.CRY AS "CTRY"
    ,A.RVW AS "RVW"

INTO MYDB.MY_TBL -- <<<<<<< NOTE

FROM MYDB.OTHER_TBL OT
JOIN [LINKEDSERVER\INST,0000].FE.dbo.tblR R
    ON OT.E = R.E
JOIN [LINKEDSERVER\INST,0000].FE.dbo.tblA A
    ON R.IR = A.IR

WHERE OT.U_ID = 'TEST'
```

Comment: I rewrote the names for my post. Please note there are no duplicate names in the original. The problem has been resolved as I forgot to include my `FROM()` subquery.